# Run exe after msi installation?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, setup-project, custom-action

Using Visual Studio 2008 to create an msi to deploy my program with a setup project. I need to know how to make the msi run the exe it just installed. A custom action? If so please explain where/how. Thanks.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This is a common question.  I don't do it with *just* a custom action.  The only way I know, is to modify the .msi after it has been generated.  I run a Javascript script as a post-build event to do exactly that.  It inserts a new dialog in the installer wizard, with a checkbox that says "Launch Application Foo?".   And then *there is a custom action* to run the app, if the checkbox is checked.

It appears as the last screen in the install Wizard sequence. Looks like this:

[image]

---

This is the script I use to modify the MSI:

```js
// EnableLaunchApplication.js <msi-file>
// Performs a post-build fixup of an msi to launch a specific file when the install has completed

// Configurable values
var checkboxChecked = true;                     // Is the checkbox on the finished dialog checked by default?
var checkboxText = "Launch [ProductName]";      // Text for the checkbox on the finished dialog
var filename = "WindowsApplication1.exe";       // The name of the executable to launch - change this to match the file you want to launch at the end of your setup

// Constant values from Windows Installer
var msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact = 1;

var msiViewModifyInsert         = 1;
var msiViewModifyUpdate         = 2;
var msiViewModifyAssign         = 3;
var msiViewModifyReplace        = 4;
var msiViewModifyDelete         = 6;

if (WScript.Arguments.Length != 1)
{
        WScript.StdErr.WriteLine(WScript.ScriptName + " file");
        WScript.Quit(1);
}

var filespec = WScript.Arguments(0);
var installer = WScript.CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
var database = installer.OpenDatabase(filespec, msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact);

var sql;
var view;
var record;

try
{
        var fileId = FindFileIdentifier(database, filename);
        if (!fileId)
                throw "Unable to find '" + filename + "' in File table";

        WScript.Echo("Updating the Control table...");
        // Modify the Control_Next of BannerBmp control to point to the new CheckBox
        sql = "SELECT `Dialog_`, `Control`, `Type`, `X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height`, `Attributes`, `Property`, `Text`, `Control_Next`, `Help` FROM `Control` WHERE `Dialog_`='FinishedForm' AND `Control`='BannerBmp'";
        view = database.OpenView(sql);
        view.Execute();
        record = view.Fetch();
        record.StringData(11) = "CheckboxLaunch";
        view.Modify(msiViewModifyReplace, record);
        view.Close();

        // Insert the new CheckBox control
        sql = "INSERT INTO `Control` (`Dialog_`, `Control`, `Type`, `X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height`, `Attributes`, `Property`, `Text`, `Control_Next`, `Help`) VALUES ('FinishedForm', 'CheckboxLaunch', 'CheckBox', '9', '201', '343', '12', '3', 'LAUNCHAPP', '{\\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}" + checkboxText + "', 'CloseButton', '|')";
        view = database.OpenView(sql);
        view.Execute();
        view.Close();

        WScript.Echo("Updating the ControlEvent table...");
        // Modify the Order of the EndDialog event of the FinishedForm to 1
        sql = "SELECT `Dialog_`, `Control_`, `Event`, `Argument`, `Condition`, `Ordering` FROM `ControlEvent` WHERE `Dialog_`='FinishedForm' AND `Event`='EndDialog'";
        view = database.OpenView(sql);
        view.Execute();
        record = view.Fetch();
        record.IntegerData(6) = 1;
        view.Modify(msiViewModifyReplace, record);
        view.Close();

        // Insert the Event to launch the application
        sql = "INSERT INTO `ControlEvent` (`Dialog_`, `Control_`, `Event`, `Argument`, `Condition`, `Ordering`) VALUES ('FinishedForm', 'CloseButton', 'DoAction', 'VSDCA_Launch', 'LAUNCHAPP=1', '0')";
        view = database.OpenView(sql);
        view.Execute();
        view.Close();

        WScript.Echo("Updating the CustomAction table...");
        // Insert the custom action to launch the application when finished
        sql = "INSERT INTO `CustomAction` (`Action`, `Type`, `Source`, `Target`) VALUES ('VSDCA_Launch', '210', '" + fileId + "', '')";
        view = database.OpenView(sql);
        view.Execute();
        view.Close();

        if (checkboxChecked)
        {
                WScript.Echo("Updating the Property table...");
                // Set the default value of the CheckBox
                sql = "INSERT INTO `Property` (`Property`, `Value`) VALUES ('LAUNCHAPP', '1')";
                view = database.OpenView(sql);
                view.Execute();
                view.Close();
        }

        database.Commit();
}
catch(e)
{
        WScript.StdErr.WriteLine(e);
        WScript.Quit(1);
}

function FindFileIdentifier(database, fileName)
{
        // First, try to find the exact file name
        var sql = "SELECT `File` FROM `File` WHERE `FileName`='" + fileName + "'";
        var view = database.OpenView(sql);
        view.Execute();
        var record = view.Fetch();
        if (record)
        {
                var value = record.StringData(1);
                view.Close();
                return value;
        }
        view.Close();

        // The file may be in SFN|LFN format.  Look for a filename in this case next
        sql = "SELECT `File`, `FileName` FROM `File`";
        view = database.OpenView(sql);
        view.Execute();
        record = view.Fetch();
        while (record)
        {
                if (StringEndsWith(record.StringData(2), "|" + fileName))
                {
                        var value = record.StringData(1);
                        view.Close();
                        return value;
                }

                record = view.Fetch();
        }
        view.Close();
}

function StringEndsWith(str, value)
{
        if (str.length < value.length)
                return false;

        return (str.indexOf(value, str.length - value.length) != -1);
}
```

I originally got this from [Aaron Stebner's blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160116052749/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/08/12/696833.aspx), and then modified it.

Save that Javascript file to the project directory (same dir as contains .vdproj), name it `ModifyMsiToEnableLaunchApplication.js` .   For each unique setup project, you need to modify that script and put the proper exe name into it.  And then, you need to set the post-build event in the Setup project to be this:

```
cscript.exe "$(ProjectDir)ModifyMsiToEnableLaunchApplication.js" "$(BuiltOuputPath)"
```

**Be sure to type the name of the macro `$(BuiltOuputPath)` correctly. The word `Ouput` is misspelled by Microsoft, and `Built` is not spelled `Build` !**

That oughtta do it.

**See also**: [this modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668274/run-exe-after-msi-installation/2998791#2998791) which does not include the "run Foo.exe" checkbox on UNINSTALL.

Comment: like a little bit of magic. I don't know if MS added the capability into the setup project for VS2010.   I think it's also possible to do this in WiX, but I've never used Wix, so this works for me.

Comment: If the interface is hidden (msi being pushed with silent install commands) will this still work?

Comment: Sure, it will still work.  Just keep the checkboxChecked var as true in the script.

Comment: I'm getting an Error: 'PostBuildEvent' failed with error code '1' 'Unspecified error'

Comment: you have to look in the build output log, to discern the problem.  First things to check: did you modify the name of the EXE at the top of the Javascript file? did you name the file properly and does the post-build event reference the proper name?

Comment: Not enough storage is available?

Comment: And yes I've named the file correctly and have modified it to the proper exe.

Comment: @Cheeso: Yes, one can do this with Wix.

Comment: Credits to the original post.. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/08/12/696833.aspx

Comment: Will this work with .bat?  If so then i think i have the answer to two of my ongoing threads

Comment: Having issues when I have some self registering COM Dll's in my setup. They just don't register in time and my app can't use these dll's; the app works perfectly when launched again from start menu. Any help?

Comment: @Trainee4Life, sounds like you need to ask a new question.

Comment: @Cheeso: New question posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422828/com-dll-exception-in-application-when-it-auto-launches-after-setup-finishes-insta

Comment: I implemented this in a msi and it works perfectly. But when calling the msi as silent install: "msiexec /i setupFile.msi /qn", the application does not start after installation. And checkbox is set to true in the js. Any ideas?

Comment: Also this adds the screen for uninstallation process as well - at the end of uninstall process.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. It also ensures (somehow, the Type field in CustomActions?) that the exe is NOT run as elevated, which is a problem with other solutions I found. Email me or DM me @WindowTabs if you would like a free license, it's the least I can do.

Comment: Be sure to type the name of the macro $(BuiltOuputPath) correctly. It took me about half an hour to realize that the word Ouput is misspelled by Microsoft, and Built is not spelled Build !

Comment: Yeah I was looking to do this myself and I used this guy's script which I found on his blog. I ran into an issue with it, but I resolved it. If anyone else is having issues please check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403627/vb-net-2005-launch-application-after-install

Comment: My code builds and  installs . But i do not see any windows to launch app (VS 2010) at the end any help?

Comment: Can someone guide me how to hide 'Lanch application'checkbox in END screen of setup. I want to run post deployment scripts always

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I just want to ask if this can be edited to put two checkbox and run another installer?

Comment: How to execute this script if we want to run app as administrator (as this solution doesn't work if we change app.manifest in our source code)? Thnx

Comment: @MarkLakata THANK YOU! In a million years I never would've noticed that on my own

Comment: @McFixit - I edited the answer to make this horrible gotcha more visible

Comment: To avoid : "Microsoft JScript compilation error: Invalid character" and subsequent "'1' 'Unspecified error'"
The file encoding for ModifyMsiToEnableLaunchApplication.js **must be ANSI**. (NOT UTF-8 Nor Unicode).

Comment: One more: After run the application, the current directory can be a different of FOO.exe.AssemblyName.CodeBase.

Comment: I can see the checkbox and it is checked but the program doesn't launch. I checked the EXE filename, even copied it from the bin folder. What may be the reason for the program not to run after installation?

Comment: Could it be because my app requires admin permission? `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`?

Comment: This worked perfectly, but after some time i started getting "The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2810." (even though the installation finishes). After logging, i found this:
"DEBUG: Error 2810:  On the dialog FinishedForm the next control pointers do not form a cycle.There is a pointer from both CheckboxLaunch and CancelButton to CloseButton"
Any help with this?

Comment: I'm trying to modify and msi file genereated by jpackage but getting `[object error]` on the first `view = database.OpenView(sql);` line.

Comment: cscript.exe is your setup solution name correct?

Comment: I am using sqlite for my wpf application , and I tried to use the above steps to run the exe after the installation , but my db files are generating in the msi path, Is this something we are manipulating in js file regarding the sqllite files ? Note I have checked the db creation path , it shows the exe path still it is creating in msi file path as well @Cheeso

Answer (score 20):

This seems to be a MUCH simpler solution:
[Visual Studio Installer > How To Launch App at End of Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168782/visual-studio-installer-how-to-launch-app-at-end-of-installer)

Comment: The original solution was required for VS2005 (and maybe VS2008) ?

Comment: Apparently this simpler solution doesn't show the checkbox option.

Comment: in this solution problem is setup will stuck right before its near to complete... almost at 98% point. and it just finishes when you exit app.

Answer (score 11):

Here is the code (without the 2 auxiliary functions `'FindFileIdentifier'` & `'StringEndsWith'` in the end - use the original ones instead) which gives us the ability to change the Ys and Heights of the controls, along with adding the Checkbox Control Visibility Conditions (see the 2 comments that are marked between `NEW - START` to `NEW - END`):

```js
// EnableLaunchApplication.js <msi-file>
// Performs a post-build fixup of an msi to launch a specific file when the install has completed


// Configurable values
var checkboxChecked = true;                     // Is the checkbox on the finished dialog checked by default?
var checkboxText = "Launch [ProductName]?";     // Text for the checkbox on the finished dialog
var filename = "*.exe";                     // The name of the executable to launch - change * to match the file name you want to launch at the end of your setup


// Constant values from Windows Installer
var msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact = 1;

var msiViewModifyInsert         = 1
var msiViewModifyUpdate         = 2
var msiViewModifyAssign         = 3
var msiViewModifyReplace        = 4
var msiViewModifyDelete         = 6



if (WScript.Arguments.Length != 1)
{
        WScript.StdErr.WriteLine(WScript.ScriptName + " file");
        WScript.Quit(1);
}

var filespec = WScript.Arguments(0);
var installer = WScript.CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
var database = installer.OpenDatabase(filespec, msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact);

var sql
var view
var record

try
{
    var fileId = FindFileIdentifier(database, filename);
    if (!fileId)
            throw "Unable to find '" + filename + "' in File table";


    WScript.Echo("Updating the Control table...");
    // Modify the Control_Next of BannerBmp control to point to the new CheckBox
    sql = "SELECT `Dialog_`, `Control`, `Type`, `X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height`, `Attributes`, `Property`, `Text`, `Control_Next`, `Help` FROM `Control` WHERE `Dialog_`='FinishedForm' AND `Control`='BannerBmp'";
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    record = view.Fetch();
    record.StringData(11) = "CheckboxLaunch";
    view.Modify(msiViewModifyReplace, record);
    view.Close();

    // NEW - START
    // Insert the new CheckBox control
    // I changed the value for Y below from 201 to 191 in order to make the checkbox more obvious to the user's eye. In order to do so, and avoid the controls 'BodyText' & 'BodyTextRemove' in the same form to
    // overlap the checkbox, I added yet 2 more sql statements that change the values of the heights for the 'BodyText' & 'BodyTextRemove' from 138 to 128. This way I can play around with the values without using
    // the Orca msi editor.
    var CheckBoxY = 191; //This was initially set to 201
    var NewHeight = 128; //This was initially set to 138
    sql = "INSERT INTO `Control` (`Dialog_`, `Control`, `Type`, `X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height`, `Attributes`, `Property`, `Text`, `Control_Next`, `Help`) VALUES ('FinishedForm', 'CheckboxLaunch', 'CheckBox', '9', '" + CheckBoxY + "', '343', '12', '3', 'LAUNCHAPP', '{\\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}" + checkboxText + "', 'CloseButton', '|')";
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    view.Close();

    sql = "Select `Dialog_`, `Control`, `Type`, `X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height`, `Attributes`, `Property`, `Text`, `Control_Next`, `Help` FROM `Control` WHERE `Dialog_` = 'FinishedForm' AND `Control` = 'BodyText'";
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    record = view.Fetch();
    record.IntegerData(7) = NewHeight;
    view.Modify(msiViewModifyReplace, record);
    view.Close();

    sql = "Select `Dialog_`, `Control`, `Type`, `X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height`, `Attributes`, `Property`, `Text`, `Control_Next`, `Help` FROM `Control` WHERE `Dialog_` = 'FinishedForm' AND `Control` = 'BodyTextRemove'";
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    record = view.Fetch();
    record.IntegerData(7) = NewHeight;
    view.Modify(msiViewModifyReplace, record);
    view.Close();
    // NEW - END

    WScript.Echo("Updating the ControlEvent table...");
    // Modify the Order of the EndDialog event of the FinishedForm to 1
    sql = "SELECT `Dialog_`, `Control_`, `Event`, `Argument`, `Condition`, `Ordering` FROM `ControlEvent` WHERE `Dialog_`='FinishedForm' AND `Event`='EndDialog'";
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    record = view.Fetch();
    record.IntegerData(6) = 1;
    view.Modify(msiViewModifyReplace, record);
    view.Close();

    // Insert the Event to launch the application
    sql = "INSERT INTO `ControlEvent` (`Dialog_`, `Control_`, `Event`, `Argument`, `Condition`, `Ordering`) VALUES ('FinishedForm', 'CloseButton', 'DoAction', 'VSDCA_Launch', 'LAUNCHAPP=1', '0')";
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    view.Close();



    WScript.Echo("Updating the CustomAction table...");
    // Insert the custom action to launch the application when finished
    sql = "INSERT INTO `CustomAction` (`Action`, `Type`, `Source`, `Target`) VALUES ('VSDCA_Launch', '210', '" + fileId + "', '')";
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    view.Close();

    if (checkboxChecked)
    {
            WScript.Echo("Updating the Property table...");
            // Set the default value of the CheckBox
            sql = "INSERT INTO `Property` (`Property`, `Value`) VALUES ('LAUNCHAPP', '1')";
            view = database.OpenView(sql);
            view.Execute();
            view.Close();
    }


    // NEW - START
    WScript.Echo("Updating the ControlCondition table...");
    // Insert the conditions where the Launch Application Checkbox appears
    sql = "INSERT INTO `ControlCondition` (`Dialog_`, `Control_`, `Action`, `Condition`) VALUES ('FinishedForm', 'CheckboxLaunch', 'Show', 'REMOVE=\"\"')";
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    view.Close();

    sql = "INSERT INTO `ControlCondition` (`Dialog_`, `Control_`, `Action`, `Condition`) VALUES ('FinishedForm', 'CheckboxLaunch', 'Hide', 'REMOVE&#060;&#062;\"\"')";
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    view.Close();
    //NEW - END


    database.Commit();
}
catch(e)
{
    WScript.StdErr.WriteLine(e);
    WScript.Quit(1);
}
```

Comment: This fixed the launch application checkbox appearing after removing!

Comment: What exactly did it fix?  It may just be that I am up too late, but I'm having trouble parsing what you wrote there, @Fidelis.

Answer (score 7):

Concerning the **"hidden checkbox bug"**, I figured out the following which is not explained by [Cheeso's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1681410/17768086) and [Muleskinner's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2027674/17768086) answers above:

The change of the script (provided by [Muleskinner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2027674/17768086)) places the Y position of the checkbox to 201 (I guess top Y pixel for the control). If you change Y to, say, 151 (in order to kind of align it in the center vertically), the bug **"suddenly"** appears. The reason for that is that there is another control in the `Control` table of the MSI, namely the `'BodyText' ('Dialog' field = 'FinishedForm')`, which its Y is set to 63 and its height to 138. That, is `138 + 63 = 201`. Therefore, if you change the Y value for the checkbox, the `'BodyText'` control overlaps the newly added control and that's why the user needs to put their mouse over in order to show the checkbox. If you have no `'BodyText'`, or its number of characters is small enough you could change (by using **Orca MSI** editor as I do, or by altering the script above) the Ys and Heights of these 2 controls in order to be able and accommodate a different Y position for the newly added checkbox. The same applies for the control: `'BodyTextRemove'` in which again we should alter its height value (which appears during uninstall).

Hopes that! this helps all the users that had the same question, as I had about this **"bug"**.

Nevertheless, the script does a really good job!

Another question was how to make invisible the **Checkbox** during uninstallation procedure?

Using the **Orca MSI** editor, I added the following 2 rows in the `ControlCondition` table of the MSI:

Row 1 (When control should be shown):

```
(Dialog)FinishedForm
(Control)CheckboxLaunch
(Action)Show
(Condition)REMOVE=""
```

Row 2 (When control should be invisible):

```
(Dialog)FinishedForm
(Control)CheckboxLaunch
(Action)Hide
(Condition)REMOVE<>""
```

**P.S.** I am using VS 2010, on windows 7 (x64), but I believe these should work with previous versions too.

Answer (score 6):

This EnableLaunchApplication.js script has a small bug where the Control_Next tab sequence is incorrect. This will cause a error code 2810 when running the installation.

Change the following line to use the "Line1" control instead of "CloseButton" so that the tab sequence of the controls are all connected.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `Control` (`Dialog_`, `Control`, `Type`, `X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height`, `Attributes`, `Property`, `Text`,
   `Control_Next`, `Help`) VALUES ('FinishedForm', 'CheckboxLaunch',
   'CheckBox', '9', '201', '343', '12', '3', 'LAUNCHAPP',
   '{\\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}" + checkboxText + "', 'CloseButton',
   '|')";
```

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the **'PostBuildEvent' failed with error code '1' 'Unspecified error'** error, change the PostBuildEvent from

```
cscript.exe \"$(ProjectDir)ModifyMsiToEnableLaunchApplication.js\" \"$(BuiltOuputPath)\"
```

to

```
cscript.exe "$(ProjectDir)ModifyMsiToEnableLaunchApplication.js" "$(BuiltOuputPath)"
```

Regarding the **hidden checkbox bug** you can edit line 54 of the script to become:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `Control` (`Dialog_`, `Control`, `Type`, `X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height`, `Attributes`, `Property`, `Text`, `Control_Next`, `Help`) VALUES ('FinishedForm', 'CheckboxLaunch', 'CheckBox', '9', '201', '343', '12', '3', 'LAUNCHAPP', '{\\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}" + checkboxText + "', 'CloseButton', '|')";
```

Answer (score 3):

After referred user3349200's suggestion, here is a completed JS script without setup error 2810.

```js
// post-build-script: CALL cscript.exe "$(ProjectDir)EnableLaunchApplication.js" "$(BuiltOuputPath)"
// EnableLaunchApplication.js <msi-file>
// Performs a post-build fixup of an msi to launch a specific file when the install has completed

// Configurable values
var checkboxChecked = true;         // Is the checkbox on the finished dialog checked by default?
var checkboxText = "Launch [ProductName]";  // Text for the checkbox on the finished dialog
var filename = "YourApp.exe";   // The name of the executable to launch - change this to match the file you want to launch at the end of your setup

// Constant values from Windows Installer
var msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact = 1;

var msiViewModifyInsert         = 1
var msiViewModifyUpdate         = 2
var msiViewModifyAssign         = 3
var msiViewModifyReplace        = 4
var msiViewModifyDelete         = 6

if (WScript.Arguments.Length != 1)
{
    WScript.StdErr.WriteLine(WScript.ScriptName + " file");
    WScript.Quit(1);
}

var filespec = WScript.Arguments(0);
var installer = WScript.CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
var database = installer.OpenDatabase(filespec, msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact);

var sql
var view
var record

try
{
    var fileId = FindFileIdentifier(database, filename);
    if (!fileId)
        throw "Unable to find '" + filename + "' in File table";


    WScript.Echo("Updating the Control table...");
    // Modify the Control_Next of BannerBmp control to point to the new CheckBox
    sql = "SELECT `Dialog_`, `Control`, `Type`, `X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height`, `Attributes`, `Property`, `Text`, `Control_Next`, `Help` FROM `Control` WHERE `Dialog_`='FinishedForm' AND `Control`='BannerBmp'";
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    record = view.Fetch();
    record.StringData(11) = "CheckboxLaunch";
    view.Modify(msiViewModifyReplace, record);
    view.Close();

    // Resize the BodyText and BodyTextRemove controls to be reasonable
    sql = "SELECT `Dialog_`, `Control`, `Type`, `X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height`, `Attributes`, `Property`, `Text`, `Control_Next`, `Help` FROM `Control` WHERE `Dialog_`='FinishedForm' AND `Control`='BodyTextRemove'";
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    record = view.Fetch();
    record.IntegerData(7) = 33;
    view.Modify(msiViewModifyReplace, record);
    view.Close();

    sql = "SELECT `Dialog_`, `Control`, `Type`, `X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height`, `Attributes`, `Property`, `Text`, `Control_Next`, `Help` FROM `Control` WHERE `Dialog_`='FinishedForm' AND `Control`='BodyText'";
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    record = view.Fetch();
    record.IntegerData(7) = 33;
    view.Modify(msiViewModifyReplace, record);
    view.Close();

    // Insert the new CheckBox control
    sql = "INSERT INTO `Control` (`Dialog_`, `Control`, `Type`, `X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height`, `Attributes`, `Property`, `Text`, `Control_Next`, `Help`) VALUES ('FinishedForm', 'CheckboxLaunch', 'CheckBox', '18', '117', '343', '12', '3', 'LAUNCHAPP', '{\\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}" + checkboxText + "', 'Line1', '|')";
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    view.Close();

    WScript.Echo("Updating the ControlEvent table...");
    // Modify the Order of the EndDialog event of the FinishedForm to 1
    sql = "SELECT `Dialog_`, `Control_`, `Event`, `Argument`, `Condition`, `Ordering` FROM `ControlEvent` WHERE `Dialog_`='FinishedForm' AND `Event`='EndDialog'";
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    record = view.Fetch();
    record.IntegerData(6) = 1;
    view.Modify(msiViewModifyReplace, record);
    view.Close();

    // Insert the Event to launch the application
    sql = "INSERT INTO `ControlEvent` (`Dialog_`, `Control_`, `Event`, `Argument`, `Condition`, `Ordering`) VALUES ('FinishedForm', 'CloseButton', 'DoAction', 'VSDCA_Launch', 'LAUNCHAPP=1', '0')";
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    view.Close();

    WScript.Echo("Updating the CustomAction table...");
    // Insert the custom action to launch the application when finished
    sql = "INSERT INTO `CustomAction` (`Action`, `Type`, `Source`, `Target`) VALUES ('VSDCA_Launch', '210', '" + fileId + "', '')";
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    view.Close();

    if (checkboxChecked)
    {
        WScript.Echo("Updating the Property table...");
        // Set the default value of the CheckBox
        sql = "INSERT INTO `Property` (`Property`, `Value`) VALUES ('LAUNCHAPP', '1')";
        view = database.OpenView(sql);
        view.Execute();
        view.Close();
    }

    database.Commit();
}
catch(e)
{
    WScript.StdErr.WriteLine(e);
    WScript.Quit(1);
}

function FindFileIdentifier(database, fileName)
{
    var sql
    var view
    var record

    // First, try to find the exact file name
    sql = "SELECT `File` FROM `File` WHERE `FileName`='" + fileName + "'";
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    record = view.Fetch();
    if (record)
    {
        var value = record.StringData(1);
        view.Close();
        return value;
    }
    view.Close();

    // The file may be in SFN|LFN format.  Look for a filename in this case next
    sql = "SELECT `File`, `FileName` FROM `File`";
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    record = view.Fetch();
    while (record)
    {
        if (StringEndsWith(record.StringData(2), "|" + fileName))
        {
            var value = record.StringData(1);
            view.Close();
            return value;
        }

        record = view.Fetch();
    }
    view.Close();
}

function StringEndsWith(str, value)
{
    if (str.length < value.length)
        return false;

    return (str.indexOf(value, str.length - value.length) != -1);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this script, but it still seems to have the issue where the run checkbox still appears during the uninstall phase. Also, I seem to be having a problem where my application doesn't actually run once the installer is finished.

Comment: Correction, I is running my application (I just had an unexpected error), however the checkbox still does appear during the uninstall phase.

Comment: for me it's work , I am able to see the checkbox but app is not auto launched after installation

Comment: This script saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.. I would write a custom action, and stick it at the end of the InstallExecutionSequence table

Comment: I don't see an InstallExecutionSequence table? Under custom actions I see Install, Commit, Rollback and uninstall. Would the custom action point to the output of the main program?

Comment: The InstallExecutionSequence table is internal to the MSI and not exposed via Visual Studio. You will need an MSI editor like Orca to edit it. Hand-editing MSIs is not a trivial task.

Comment: I agree - hand-editing MSIs is not easy.  Not is it easy or trivial using Orca.  You can use the script I provided below to automate the task.  Quick and easy, tested and proven.

Comment: I know the question is for VS2008 but for VS2010 it looks fairly easy to create a custom Commit action. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d.aspx