# Patching an MSI created with Visual Studio 2005 Setup projects .vdproj

Tags: installation, windows-installer, patch, setup-project

Folks,

What should be the process of patching an MSI file that was created by VS 2005 using the setup projects ?

I need to create an MSP file that will replace a few files only; is this doable via VS or any other tools ?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify MSI files by using the COM object with the ProgId [WindowsInstaller.Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369432(VS.85).aspx).  It's pretty easy to do via JavaScript, or C++, or C#, or whatever language you like.

I don't know what an MSP is. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668274/run-exe-after-msi-installation/1681410#1681410) shows a a Javascript program that modifies an MSI file in place.