# Launch program after msi installation

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer

I've created a msi installer with visual studio 2008. I'd like to launch the installed program right after the installer has finished.

1) How to add a User Interace like many installers have that asks if to launch the app now?

2) Can I create a custom action that runs the app with user privileges?

Comment: ok, i've managed but now the problem is that running the app works but the app uses %appdata% and %appdata% of the msi is not the user's dir. it' commonappdata... any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying you want to launch the application with a working directory other than the temporary folder which your `msi` is using, specifically the directory in which the actual `msi` is located?

Comment: Also you may want to self-answer with your solution, for extra reputation points.

Comment: I'd like to run the app in the same dir as it's now launched but I think I need to run it with user rights or with the normal user not with the msi setup user 'cause the %appdata% path of the msi-setup-user is different from the user's...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create a js custom dialog described here: [Run exe after msi installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668274/run-exe-after-msi-installation)

or you can make a custom action at commit that calls [TARGETDIR]\YourApp.exe

Comment: problem is that the wrong user is executing the app in that case. the msi seems to have its own user that is just for the setuo (i guess for some reason e.g. rollback). any ideas?