# How can I execute a Custom Action as System user with Wix 3.0, before checking to see if files are in use?

Tags: wix

So I have a Wix 3.0 project that installs an IIS7 Native Code Module. When uninstalling I would like to be able to shut down the IIS7 application pools before deleting the file so that a reboot is not necessary.

I am using the appcmd utility to shut down the app pools in a CustomAction element, but when I attempt to do an uninstall I get this error before the customaction is ever invoked:

> The setup must update files or
>   services that cannot be updated while
>   the system is running. If you choose
>   to continue, a reboot will be required
>   to complete the setup.

I have the "After='InstallInitialize'" property set on the CustomAction, because the documentation says that any deferred/not-impersonated custom action must come between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize.

So is there some way to have a custom action execute before this check for files in use is made? Or disable this check for a given file, or make the check happen later in the sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can specify the order for actions to occur by modifying the Sequence column in [the InstallExecuteSequence table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369500(VS.85).aspx) within the MSI file.

[Get the ORCA tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557(VS.85).aspx) to examine the MSI file to see what  I mean, and [use a Javascript script to modify the MSI as appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668274/run-exe-after-msi-installation/1681410#1681410).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. I actually found that the problem I was having only happened when I compiled the WiX project in Debug mode, but this seems to be a good answer to my question and will be useful.