# Run chm after msi installation?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-project, custom-action, chm

I would like to launch a Windows Compiled HTML Help file with .chm extension after my MSI installation.

There is a script at [Run exe after msi installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668274/run-exe-after-msi-installation) that inserts a checkbox (had to use the two bugs fixes further down) into the last page of the installation.

The script completes but I'm not sure if the LAUNCHAPP=1 can only launch executables after the installation.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate question, short answer... `hh.exe` is associated with `.CHM` files, so you need to call that.

```
hh.exe MyHelpFile.chm
```

Comment: Thanks. Was a long day yesterday!

Comment: Have been looking at implementing this with the script on that page and it only allows executables to be run that are in the file list of the MSI.  I'll keep investigating.

Really need to run the following command after install: %SystemRoot%\hh.exe "[TARGET_DIR]\Help\Help.chm"