# Copy/install application to Program Files automatically when it is first run

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When execution an application for the first time, I want this running applicationto be copied to C:\Program Files\

Say I give this application to my friend then he executes it for the first time and this application must do the copy to C:\Program Files\

How to code it?

Comment: what if your application is running on a limited user account? by the way just use `IO.File.Copy()`

Comment: You're not going to have the necessary privileges to access the Program Files folder. You will have to either create an installer, or follow PM's advice and utilize ClickOnce deployment for your application.

Comment: forget C:\program files be it desktop

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a Click Once kind of application. Check the link [Click Once Deplyment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @JeremyThompson. But If user2166628 ready to change the location as per his recent comment in question. Then it can be useful.

Comment: +1 showing some sportsmanship :) ps I deleted my previous comment but I put in my 2 cents in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move an EXE file while it is being executed, you will either:

- have code that copies the EXE to another location

`IO.File.Copy()`

- or have an installer

[`Click Once`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) installs to a really [obsecure location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359026/how-to-get-folder-path-for-clickonce-application), not program files. It does NOT require admin.

If you add a [`MSI setup project`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c(v=vs.71).aspx) to your solution you can see this [answer to hardcode the install path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676140/visual-studio-2008-setup-project-fixing-the-location-of-installed-kit/2677159#2677159) to C:\Program Files\

If you choose the MSI solution you will need Admin to install. Because the setup.exe is responsible for the downloading/installing components (such as dotnet) it requires Admin to be executed.

If you know the PC your application is going to be installed on already has the .Net Framework & etc then the easiest way to avoid the UAC prompt is to run the MSI not the setup.exe. Running the MSI wont ask for admin.

You can also follow this answer to make your [upgrades install to the same folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474320/install-to-same-path-when-upgrading-application/11490003#11490003).