# How to Launch executable after installation is complete

Tags: windows-installer

I am using VS 2010. I have created a setup project to install my WPF application. Once the installation is complete, I would like the executable to launch. How do I get the executable to launch after installation is complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a custom action that happens after the Commit installation action, which will launch the application. You will not be able to let the user choose whether to launch the app from the last dialog using this method, as you may have seen with other installers; Setup Projects do not support that feature. You may be able to play around with adding an additional dialog into the process that will allow the user to choose, but it won't be a choice on the last dialog before clicking Finish.

More reading:

[Create Custom Action to Start Application and Exit Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172406/create-custom-action-to-start-application-and-exit-installer)

Comment: ok, thanks, the custom action in the commit works great. But there is one problem. During the install, after my app is launched, the installer's "Installing" dialog stays on the screen until I exit my app. Then the installer goes to it's "Finished" dialog. How can I launch my app but also have the installer continue through it's process?

Comment: That question should be answered in the question I linked to; the person posting that question had that exact problem.