# How to run a process as current user privilege from an admin process

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-vista, manifest, windows-security

When a setup program(built by like Inno Setup) does launch a process, the process always be run as administrator privilege. -because setup program had been run as admin.

I want to run the child process as current user's privilege.
Is there a good way?

Comment: Note: I would recommend using the answer by Larry Osterman, as he works DEVELOPING Windows at MS (see his blog at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/). Since the code pointed by Bradley is a kludge (as he do points), it could stop working in any moment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although it is not considered best practice (or even good practice), it is possible to launch a medium IL process from a high/admin IL process:

[See this post on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/createprocessexplorerleve.aspx?msg=3264682)

I can confirm that this code works on Vista 32 and 64-bit with and without UAC enabled.

Comment: This can fail in multiple ways: A)Explorer is not running. B)Explorer is elevated. C)Explorer is running as a different user because the secondary logon service aka runas was used: Explorer.exe=User1, cmd.exe(or some other process)=User2(cmd.exe started by runas, this is the user you want) YourElevated.exe=(Admin)User3

Comment: @Anders Although it is not a fool-proof solution, it is relatively safe to assume that a setup program (as in the context of the original question) will be run interactively; ensuring that A is true. C is true in the vast majority of environments. If either of the 3 scenarios you stated are true, i'm sure it's not unreasonable for an elevation prompt to be presented to the user.

Comment: @Bradley Smith: Another scenario; The system is so messed up that it has to be booted in safe mode with command line (Broken shell extension or malware that keeps crashing the shell) Then the only processes will be cmd.exe, add/remove programs and the uninstaller.

Comment: Just a brief comment - it's *never* safe to assume that a setupo program is being run interactively. Doing so will make you the bane of system administrators worldwide.

Answer (score 13):

This question comes up every 3 or 4 months internally at MSFT.

The answer that the security folks give is: You can't.  When the elevated process token is created, there are changes made to the token that can't be undone.

Your best bet is to have a launcher application that runs your elevated setup program and then when the elevated setup program is completed, turns around and runs your child process.

Comment: I keep telling people this over and over, but they never listen. Finally someone from MS speaks up.

Comment: Hey, an answer from Larry Osterman itself! The accepted solution looked a bit like a kludge and this confirm it. Unrelated: It would be also good if you can convince Raymond Chen to awnswer questions here when his blog post queue reaches two years :-) .

Comment: Totally off topic, but his queue is over 2 years at this point :).

Answer (score 0):

As a launcher you can use the portable powershell app deployment kit ([Link](https://discourse.psappdeploytoolkit.com/)). You can edit the deploy-application.ps1 and use Execute-ProcessAsUser to run applications/scripts with the current user even when you launched the powershell app deployment kit as admin