# How to run a process as non-admin from an elevated PowerShell console?

Tags: windows, powershell, elevated-privileges, start-process

Maybe there is a way to do it with [Start-Process](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx) cmdlet that I cannot find? The other related Q/A's I found on StackOverflow such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3939731/450913), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/196949/450913) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1173630/450913) all give a solution to do this with a custom C# code. My question is specifically, is there any straightforward way to do this in PowerShell? i.e. you are in an elevated PS console and want to run a process as non-admin.

Comment: That's unusually advanced functionality, PowerShell may not be an appropriate choice.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20218076/batch-file-drop-elevated-privileges-run-a-command-as-original-user

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can specify the `TrustLevel` with `runas.exe`, effectively running "restricted"

```
runas /trustlevel:0x20000 "powershell.exe -command 'whoami /groups |clip'"
```

You should see in the output from `whoami` that the `Administrators` group in your token is marked as "Used for Deny only"

---

[image]

Comment: `0x20000` leaves the account's "High Mandatory Level" label enabled. With `0x1000` only "Everyone", "Users", and "Authenticated Users" are enabled. `/showtrustlevels` doesn't even list this level. Is this documented anywhere? It isn't mentioned in the following article, which does mention `0x20000`: [New ACLs Improve Security in Windows Vista](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.acl.aspx).

Comment: @eryksun my mistake, trustlevel != integrity level. From the article: "As a point of interest, trustlevel 0x20000 gives you a token with the normal set of SIDs but stripped privileges"

Comment: I read the article. I was asking about `0x1000`, which as I mentioned sets all groups to deny (including the integrity label) except for the groups "Everyone", "Users", and "Authenticated Users". I only found this by experimenting. It doesn't appear to be documented anywhere.

Comment: Interesting, I get a `The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142)` whenever I try to launch anything with `/trustlevel:0x1000` on Windows 7 SP1, no matter the trustlevel of the calling process. What version of Windows did you succeed with this on?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7, but my shell is running in session 0. It won't work on an interactive desktop.

Comment: This no longer works as of Windows 11 Update 22H2 https://superuser.com/questions/1749696/parameter-is-incorrect-when-using-runas-with-trustlevel-after-windows-11-22h2

Answer (score 6):

Another, limited, way: Make Windows Explorer launch it for you

```
PS C:\> explorer.exe "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
```

Just use the full path and extension. But **it does NOT** accept parameters.

I tried creating a batch file. But explorer refuses to launch `.BAT` or `.CMD`.

EDIT:
You can also use [gsudo](https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo) for this:

```
gsudo --integrity medium MyApp.exe
```

Answer (score 5):

When you dig into this problem, as mentioned by the linked tasks, there is no way to run a UAC "non" elevated process from a elevated process.   Since this is exactly what I required and the runas solution didn't work for me I converted the code workaround supplied by Microsoft to use a scheduled task to Start a "non" elevated process.

Example of running powershell.exe as a "non" elevated process from a elevated powershell prompt:

```
$apppath = "powershell.exe"
$taskname = "Launch $apppath"
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $apppath
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date)
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName $taskname | Out-Null
Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskname
Start-Sleep -s 1
Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskname -Confirm:$false
```

The above powershell commands only work on Windows Server 2012 / Windows 8 and greater only.

Or you can use the [SCHTASKS.EXE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) application instead to cover most versions of windows:

```
$apppath = "powershell.exe"
$taskname = "Launch $apppath"
schtasks /create /SC ONCE /ST 23:59 /TN $taskname /TR $apppath
schtasks /run /tn $taskname
Start-Sleep -s 1
schtasks /delete /tn $taskname /F
```

Comment: This approach is apparently more thorough (doesn't interfere with my screenshot app's shortcuts, when the new window has focus).

Comment: To run task on battery power, I added a Register-ScheduledTask argument: `-Settings (New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries)`

Answer (score 1):

You can run a non-admin process from an elevated session by passing in the credential of the user you want to run as. You can use `Get-Credential` if you want to run interactively, or you can use `Import-Clixml` or [SecretStore](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/secretmanagement-and-secretstore-are-generally-available/) or some other established mechanism for storing and retrieving credentials if you want a script to run unattended. E.g.:

```
$credential = Get-Credential -UserName $Env:USERNAME
# or
$credential = Import-Clixml -Path 'C:\MyCredential.cred'

Start-Process -FilePath pwsh.exe -ArgumentList '-noprofile' -Credential $credential -Wait
```

Answer (score -7):

in `start-process` exist switch `runas` like

```
start-process powershell -verb runAs
```

but still uac check you if in your system uac on you should first bypass **uac** there are many way exist for bypass uac but all ways doesn't work in all windows like windows 8
if you write script for run process then [compile to exe](https://ps2exe.codeplex.com) you can use program like [runasadmin](https://level-23.eu/forum/showthread.php?t=32278) for run as admin your exe in system but still not work in windows 8

Comment: This appears to be the exact opposite of the question's desired answer. Per the Help for `Start-Process` "The RunAs verb starts the process with permissions of a member of the Administrators group on the computer. This is the same as starting Windows PowerShell with the "Run as administrator" option."