# How can I tell a program NOT to run as an administrator when running from the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

I have DS4Windows which runs as a task, and therefore has certain admin privileges.Problem is, when I set certain button combos to open programs it runs *those* with admin privileges too, which I don't want.

I tried using the `RUNAS` command in a .bat file to run as my own account, however even using `/savecred` it still prompts me for my password every few times, which as you can imagine is a major PITA when I'm halfway across the room with a wireless controller.

Is there any way to tell a program not to run as administrator with a command line argument?

Comment: Have you tried to run command with non-admin provileges by this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569292/)?

Comment: I actually found that soon after posting. It was a nightmare googling the problem though since every result is just for "How to run as administrator," and not "how to NOT run as administrator." Their solution worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569292/how-to-run-a-process-as-non-admin-from-an-elevated-powershell-console)

Turns out googling the problem is a nightmare as everyone posts "how to run as administrator," instead of "how to NOT run as administrator."

In short, using the following command does the job:

```
RUNAS /trustlevel:0x20000 "\"C:\Path\To\Exe\""
```