# Force file to autostart with Windows in VS's MSI setup

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, startup

How do I make my executable file start with Windows in Visual Studio's Windows Installation project (MSI setup creator)?

Tried to add registry keys, look into 'Assembly' properties. I have the MSI project compile and it installs fine to the folder but I need it to run

a) After installation is complete
b) Every time Windows starts.

Thank you

Comment: It might be worth looking here for launching the EXE after install: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3169040/4181058 and also here to launch the exe after each login: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys

Answer (score 0):

> [**On Scheduled Tasks versus Windows Services**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216281/uninstall-custom-action-not-deleting-registry-key/48426736#48426736). See this previous answer for longer descriptions of the below summary items. I don't use this installer tools, so detailed steps I can't do right now.
>
> [**When should I use a scheduled task instead of a Windows Service?**](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#ServiceVsTaskScheduler)

***Startup Folder***: You can use the **`Windows startup folder`** [as suggested here - allusers](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=34660):

- **`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`**
- **`C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`**

Quick access: **`Windows logo key + R`** **`=>`** **`shell:startup`**.

***Windows Service***: Windows services are usually set to run on boot / system startup. They can also start on demand or be disabled. There used to be a tool called [Microsoft SRVANY](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSrvany) allowing applications to run as services ([how-to](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#UsingSrvany)), but I am not sure how well it works anymore.

***Scheduled Task***: It is possible to launch tasks on every boot using the task scheduler. These can run as a specific user.

***AutoRun Registry***: You can register something to run on login in the registry - [Run and RunOnce Registry Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys):

- **`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`**
- **`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`**
- **`HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`**
- **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`**
- **`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`**

***Drivers***: I suppose one can mention drivers as well. They load on startup. They need signing and the complexity is high. Nobody should use this for anything casual - to state the obvious.

***Group Policy***: Group policy can run specific programs on logon - either for a specific user or for all users. [How to Run Programs Automatically When a User Logs On](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/240791/how-to-run-programs-automatically-when-a-user-logs-on) (**`Winkey + R`** **`=>`** **`gpedit.msc`**):

All computer users:

```
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Run These Programs at User Logon
```

Specific user:

```
User Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Run These Programs at User Logon
```

---

[***Autoruns.exe***](https://live.sysinternals.com/Autoruns64.exe): [Sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) has the tool [autoruns.exe](https://live.sysinternals.com/Autoruns64.exe) which will show you just how many ways there are to start something on system startup:

[image: autoruns.exe]

---

***Links***:

- https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-launch-app-logon.html
- [How to make a program run at startup (as admin) with WiX on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67420403/how-to-make-a-program-run-at-startup-as-admin-with-wix-on-windows-10)