# .MSI Launch Multiple EXE's After Installation

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, windows-installer

There already exists [a good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168782/visual-studio-installer-how-to-launch-app-at-end-of-installer) to causing a .MSI to launch a single EXE at the very end of installation. The programmer creates a Javascript file that is executed by Visual Studio as a POST-BUILD-EVENT of the relevant .vdproj project that generates the .MSI. The Javascript modifies the .MSI generated by the .vdproj project as explained in the link.

[Microsoft writes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/controlevent-table):

> An integer used to order several events tied to the same control.This must be a non - negative number. This field may be left blank.

...implying that a single control in the final dialog box presented during installation can fire multiple events. I modified the code accordingly, to cause the launch of two EXE's, but only the second EXE is ever launched. How can I get two EXE's to launch without using two buttons? Better yet, is it possible to get the EXE's to launch without using any controls?

```
    WScript.Echo("Inserting events to launch the applications...");
    // Insert the Event to launch the application
    sql = "INSERT INTO `ControlEvent` (`Dialog_`, `Control_`, `Event`, `Argument`, `Condition`, `Ordering`) VALUES ('FinishedForm', 'CloseButton', 'DoAction', 'VSDCA_Launch0', 'LAUNCHAPPS=1', '0')";
    sql = "INSERT INTO `ControlEvent` (`Dialog_`, `Control_`, `Event`, `Argument`, `Condition`, `Ordering`) VALUES ('FinishedForm', 'CloseButton', 'DoAction', 'VSDCA_Launch1', 'LAUNCHAPPS=1', '1')";
    
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    view.Close();



    WScript.Echo("Updating the CustomAction table...");
    // Insert the custom actions to launch the applications when finished
    sql = "INSERT INTO `CustomAction` (`Action`, `Type`, `Source`, `Target`) VALUES ('VSDCA_Launch0', '210', '" + fileId1 + "', '')";
    sql = "INSERT INTO `CustomAction` (`Action`, `Type`, `Source`, `Target`) VALUES ('VSDCA_Launch1', '210', '" + fileId2 + "', '')";
    view = database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    view.Close();
```

```
I expected this to launch two EXE's.

Here is the relevant log text:

    MSI (c) (1C:E8) [08:49:24:280]: Doing action: FinishedForm
    Action 8:49:24: FinishedForm. 
    Action start 8:49:24: FinishedForm.
    MSI (c) (1C:E8) [08:49:24:280]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'FinishedForm' 
    MSI (c) (1C:84) [08:49:24:280]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
    DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line1 on dialog FinishedForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
    The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FinishedForm, Line1, to the right
    MSI (c) (1C:84) [08:49:24:280]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
    DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line2 on dialog FinishedForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
    The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FinishedForm, Line2, to the right
    MSI (c) (1C:84) [08:49:24:296]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
    DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control BannerBmp on dialog FinishedForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
    The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FinishedForm, BannerBmp, to the right
    MSI (c) (1C:84) [08:49:24:296]: Note: 1: 2262 2: CheckBox 3: -2147287038 
    Action 8:49:24: FinishedForm. Dialog created
    MSI (c) (1C:84) [08:49:28:499]: Doing action: VSDCA_Launch1
    Action 8:49:28: VSDCA_Launch1. 
    Action start 8:49:28: VSDCA_Launch1.
    MSI (c) (1C:84) [08:49:28:499]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'VSDCA_Launch1' 
    Action ended 8:49:28: FinishedForm. Return value 1.
    Action ended 8:49:28: INSTALL. Return value 1.
    Action ended 8:49:28: VSDCA_Launch1. Return value 0.
```

Comment: Have you tried to run your installer with LOG (msiexec /i <your.msi> /l*v log.txt) and see what does it say?

Comment: Log output added.