# How to launch the application after the setup finishes, but in non-elevated mode?

Tags: windows-installer, setup-project

When I launch my appliation after the setup completes, it launches the application in elevated mode. One of the problems, that this creates is that the user can no longer drag drop files into the application.

Running the application from Start Menu works fine.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was answered by the following post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668274/run-exe-after-msi-installation). I also had faced few problems related to COM Dll registration which was solved by a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486353/what-vsdca-launch-mean-in-custom-action-script).

Answer (score 0):

The WiX manual has a topic how to do this: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/run_program_after_install.htm