# What VSDCA_Launch mean in Custom Action script

Tags: .net, visual-studio, setup-deployment, installscript-msi

I want to launch an application after installation with Visual Studio setup&deployment output. I follow 
[the article 'How do I launch an application after install in a Visual Studio Setup Project'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247446/how-do-i-launch-an-application-after-install-in-a-visual-studio-setup-project). 
It has a solution that using Custom Action to add a checkbox and launch the application after installation. But I still have a problem, the application has launched with the working directory was difference from the target directory. Therefore it can't read XML configuration file. I've read more about Custom Action at [Custom Action Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372048%28VS.85%29.aspx) and think I should use action 34 or 35 but I'm still confuse how to use.

The original insert action statement in script is:
sql = "INSERT INTO `CustomAction` (`Action`, `Type`, `Source`, `Target`) VALUES ('VSDCA_Launch', '210', '" + fileId + "', '')";

I known that 210 is 18 + 192 but don't know what VSDCA_Launch mean. How can I launch the app with target directory. Thank you.

**EDIT**

I've changed to 226 = 34 + 192 and it work fine.

sql = "INSERT INTO `CustomAction` (`Action`, `Type`, `Source`, `Target`) VALUES ('VSDCA_Launch', '226', 'TARGETDIR', '[TARGETDIR]\App.exe')";

Answer (score 2):

Just a minor correction to the above solution:
There's a backslash missing. I think it may have to do with the formatting of the post.
The line should be:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO CustomAction (Action, Type, Source, Target) VALUES ('VSDCA_Launch', '226', 'TARGETDIR', '[TARGETDIR]\\App.exe')";
```

Comment: My application wouldn't start with the original launch line from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60565/how-to-run-executable-at-end-of-setup-project this launch line solved it though. Thanks!