# COM DLL exception in application when it auto launches after setup finishes installation!

Tags: windows-installer, installation

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668274/run-exe-after-msi-installation) solution to modify the MSI to include a checkbox for user to decide whether s/he wants to launch the application after setup exits.

Although everything works just fine, what I noticed was the application was not able to use any COM DLL's registered during the setup when it was auto launched. The app works perfectly when launched again from start menu.

I have tested it on Windows XP and Windows 7.

The COM DLL's have been marked as self registering dll's in the setup project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it work. The problem was that the target directory was not specified. The bug fix was mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486353/what-vsdca-launch-mean-in-custom-action-script).

I changed one of the lines in script to:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `CustomAction` (`Action`, `Type`, `Source`, `Target`) VALUES ('VSDCA_Launch', '226', 'TARGETDIR', '[TARGETDIR]\\" + filename + " " + arguments + "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an answer to such a specific question since I don't have your installer and application in a test lab to do some basic profiling and troubleshooting.  However I will throw an idea at the wall and see if it sticks:

Is your working directory different between the shortcut and creating the process from the installer?  Depending on how your COM was registered, this can make a difference.

Comment: Could it be elevation? The tested OS wasn't specified.

Comment: Hard to say, I wanted to start with the simple case. :-)

Comment: I didn't get the different directory issue. Can you rephrase it? Also, I added few more details to the question.

Comment: Does your application work if you log on as a different user? ( One that didn't do the install. )

Comment: Yes it does work. It just doesn't work the first time application is auto launched.