# Application does not start after running setup with postbuild event

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-deployment, post-build-event

I've used the script from this thread: [Run exe after msi installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668274/run-exe-after-msi-installation) respectively this site: [Mailbag: How can I customize an MSI in the Visual Studio setup/deployment project?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2006/08/12/mailbag-how-can-i-customize-an-msi-in-the-visual-studio-setupdeployment-project/)

The checkbox on the finished dialog shows up but my application doesn't start after pressing finish. Nothing happens.

I've tried different lines:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `CustomAction` (`Action`, `Type`, `Source`, `Target`) VALUES ('VSDCA_Launch', '210', '" + fileId + "', '')";
```

or

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `CustomAction` (`Action`, `Type`, `Source`, `Target`) VALUES ('VSDCA_Launch', '226', 'TARGETDIR', 'MyProgram.exe')";
```

Any ideas or is it possible to debug the script or write a log with further informations to find out what exactly doesn't work? The application need administrator rights. Does this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Formatted***: The fact that `notepad.exe` works probably means that you need a full path (`notepad.exe` is in the system path and can
>   hence be invoked without a path, other binaries need full path).
>
> Did you try to do **`[#filekey]`** as in **`[#MyProgram.exe]`** as
>   value in the Target field? The reference must match a **File table**
>   entry. So look in the **first column** of the **File table** to
>   determine what the file identifier is, and use that in the Target
>   field.
>
> Check out the documentation for [**Formatted**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/formatted).
>
> ***WiX?***: By the way, is it an option to migrate to WiX? Not to annoy you, but [there are some major problems with Visual Studio
>   Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944893/129130) for long term
>   use. Maybe give it a quick skim.

***File Table***:

[image: File Table]

***Shortcut Table***:

[image: Shortcut Table]

---

Leaving original answer below:

---

***Quick Test***: Maybe first check this: [What VSDCA_Launch mean in Custom Action script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486353/what-vsdca-launch-mean-in-custom-action-script)

---

***Logging***: Have you enabled logging to determine what is going on? Please check [**the Logging section in this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52085651/129130) for a quick "how to".

***Dry Run***: I suppose you could slipstream **`notepad.exe`** in there instead of your own executable to see if it launches OK when admin rights are not required. All you need is a test build and a test run.

***Incomplete***: I am betting you have forgotten something when post processing the MSI though. My guess is a simple formatting issues such as described by the post linked above.

Comment: The advice with notepad is interesting, because notepad starts without any problems. But when I put notepad2.exe into the target dir it doesn't start. Apparently the directory can't be found.

Comment: I'll have a look at Wix. Would you prefer it over InnoSetup?

Comment: Certainly. Much better for corporate / silent deployment - provided you keep it simple and standardized. How big is the package?

Comment: Do you mean the filesize of the created  setupfile? This is currently 70 MB.

Comment: WiX is a bit fiddly, but it has everything you need in terms of flexibility. Other than that I tend to bug people with these two links of mine: [List of MSI Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130). [Deployment Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49632260/129130). For some reason a rather messy answer of mine has been upvoted on the topic of: ["WiX Quick Start"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180276/discussion-between-stein-asmul-and-user1673665).