# MSI run after install WITH command arguments

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

I'm using script at [Run exe after msi installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668274/run-exe-after-msi-installation) to add a "run application" window at the end of my install. However, i would like to pass a commandargument to the application, how can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a property in you msi package (for example, INSTALLDIR), you may pass in as parameter using syntax: [PROPERTYNAME].

So, you should find your custom action and add into exe String list of properties (for example, "[INSTALLDIR] " "[COMMONFILESDIR64]" etc)

Run msi installer with command line: msiexec /i(or x) setup.msi /l*vx log.txt - and see the log file. msiexec will write ALL properties to this file.

Comment: thanks, but I don't quite understand. This is my action: sql = "INSERT INTO `CustomAction` (`Action`, `Type`, `Source`, `Target`) VALUES ('VSDCA_Launch', '210', '" + fileId + "', '')"; Where should I put this?

Comment: figured it out, i just had to put the argument under "target". thanks