# MSI "run" checkbox shown on uninstall?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

I'm using the code at [Run exe after msi installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668274/run-exe-after-msi-installation), and it shows the checkbox when uninstall is run. How to modify it so the checkbox is not shown when uninstalling?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer by akarkoulis on that very question...

> Using the Orca msi editor I added the
>   following 2 rows in the
>   ControlCondition table of the msi:
>
> Row 1 (When control should be shown):
>
> (Dialog)FinishedForm
>   (Control)CheckboxLaunch (Action)Show
>   (Condition)REMOVE=""
>
> Row 2 (When control should be
>   invisible):
>
> (Dialog)FinishedForm
>   (Control)CheckboxLaunch (Action)Hide
>   (Condition)REMOVE<>""