# HowTo run a script after MSI installation was completed? MSI created with VS2010 + Setup Wizard

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-wizard, post-install

*Targets:* I have MyAPP.exe (build in VS2010) & MyDriver.sys (build with VS2010 + WinDDK)

What I'm trying to do: is to create a **Setup Wizard** project, which can run post-install action, for example, I need to install the driver after installation succesfully completed like this:

```
rundll32.exe setupapi,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 132 .\MyDriver.inf
```

Another words, I need to run CMD script file (pre or port install, the order not is the real problem), with my MSI package simultaneously.

Is there any solution for me?

Thank you!

---

PS. Yes, I had already read some topics, like [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668274/run-exe-after-msi-installation), [link 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/08/12/696833.aspx) and others, but they seems to me too "heavy". Maybe some more easy solution exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you should consider to write your own installer class.

Maybe [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/Installation.aspx) tutorial helps you.