# Adding Launch Checkboxes to MSI Installer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, setup-project, custom-action

I am trying to achieve something like this:
[Run exe after msi installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668274/run-exe-after-msi-installation)

However my problem is that I need 2 check boxes to launch 2 different exes.
I duplicated the code and attempted to make changes. Leaving me to wonder:

- What fields are unique to each checkbox?

Or is it just not feasible?

Partial js file:

```
//First CHECKBOX
WScript.Echo("Adding FirstCheckbox...");

        var fileId = FindFileIdentifier(database, expertFilename);
        if (!fileId)
                throw "Unable to find '" + expertFilename + "' in File table";

        appName = "Rating"

        WScript.Echo("Updating the Control table...");
        // Modify the Control_Next of BannerBmp control to point to the new CheckBox
        sql = "SELECT `Dialog_`, `Control`, `Type`, `X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height`, `Attributes`, `Property`, `Text`, `Control_Next`, `Help` FROM `Control` WHERE `Dialog_`='FinishedForm' AND `Control`='BannerBmp'";
        view = database.OpenView(sql);
        view.Execute();
        record = view.Fetch();
        record.StringData(11) = "CheckboxLaunch";
        view.Modify(msiViewModifyReplace, record);
        view.Close();

        // Insert the new CheckBox control
        sql = "INSERT INTO `Control` (`Dialog_`, `Control`, `Type`, `X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height`, `Attributes`, `Property`, `Text`, `Control_Next`, `Help`) VALUES ('FinishedForm', 'CheckboxLaunch', 'CheckBox', '9', '201', '343', '12', '3', 'LAUNCHAPP', '{\\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}" + checkboxText + appName + "', 'CheckboxLaunch1', '|')";
        view = database.OpenView(sql);
        view.Execute();
        view.Close();


        WScript.Echo("Updating the ControlEvent table...");
        // Modify the Order of the EndDialog event of the FinishedForm to 1
        sql = "SELECT `Dialog_`, `Control_`, `Event`, `Argument`, `Condition`, `Ordering` FROM `ControlEvent` WHERE `Dialog_`='FinishedForm' AND `Event`='EndDialog'";


        view = database.OpenView(sql);
        view.Execute();
        record = view.Fetch();
        record.IntegerData(6) = 1;
        view.Modify(msiViewModifyReplace, record);
        view.Close();

        // Insert the Event to launch the application
        sql = "INSERT INTO `ControlEvent` (`Dialog_`, `Control_`, `Event`, `Argument`, `Condition`, `Ordering`) VALUES ('FinishedForm', 'CloseButton', 'DoAction', 'VSDCA_Launch', 'LAUNCHAPP=1', '0')";
        view = database.OpenView(sql);
        view.Execute();
        view.Close();



        WScript.Echo("Updating the CustomAction table...");
        // Insert the custom action to launch the application when finished
        sql = "INSERT INTO `CustomAction` (`Action`, `Type`, `Source`, `Target`) VALUES ('VSDCA_Launch', '210', '" + fileId + "', '')";
        view = database.OpenView(sql);
        view.Execute();
        view.Close();

        if (checkboxChecked)
        {
                WScript.Echo("Updating the Property table...");
                // Set the default value of the CheckBox
                sql = "INSERT INTO `Property` (`Property`, `Value`) VALUES ('LAUNCHAPP', '1')";
                view = database.OpenView(sql);
                view.Execute();
                view.Close();
        }

        database.Commit();

//Other CHECKBOX
WScript.Echo("Adding other Checkbox...");


        fileId = FindFileIdentifier(database, micsFilename);
        if (!fileId)
                throw "Unable to find '" + micsFilename + "' in File table";


        appName = "Policy Managment"

        WScript.Echo("Updating the Control table...");
        // Modify the Control_Next of BannerBmp control to point to the new CheckBox
        sql = "SELECT `Dialog_`, `Control`, `Type`, `X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height`, `Attributes`, `Property`, `Text`, `Control_Next`, `Help` FROM `Control` WHERE `Dialog_`='FinishedForm' AND `Control`='BannerBmp'";
        view = database.OpenView(sql);
        view.Execute();
        record = view.Fetch();
        record.StringData(11) = "CheckboxLaunch1";

       // view.Modify(msiViewModifyReplace, record);
        view.Close();

        // Insert the new CheckBox control
        sql = "INSERT INTO `Control` (`Dialog_`, `Control`, `Type`, `X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height`, `Attributes`, `Property`, `Text`, `Control_Next`, `Help`) VALUES ('FinishedForm', 'CheckboxLaunch1', 'CheckBox', '9', '201', '343', '12', '3', 'LAUNCHAPP2', '{\\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}" + checkboxText + appName + "', 'CloseButton', '|')";
        view = database.OpenView(sql);
        view.Execute();
        view.Close();


        WScript.Echo("Updating the ControlEvent table...");
        // Modify the Order of the EndDialog event of the FinishedForm to 1
        sql = "SELECT `Dialog_`, `Control_`, `Event`, `Argument`, `Condition`, `Ordering` FROM `ControlEvent` WHERE `Dialog_`='FinishedForm' AND `Event`='EndDialog'";
        view = database.OpenView(sql);
        view.Execute();
        record = view.Fetch();
        record.IntegerData(6) = 1;
        view.Modify(msiViewModifyReplace, record);
        view.Close();

        // Insert the Event to launch the application
        sql = "INSERT INTO `ControlEvent` (`Dialog_`, `Control_`, `Event`, `Argument`, `Condition`, `Ordering`) VALUES ('FinishedForm', 'CloseButton', 'DoAction', 'VSDCA_Launch1', 'LAUNCHAPP2=1', '0')";

        view = database.OpenView(sql);
        view.Execute();
        view.Close();

        WScript.Echo("Updating the CustomAction table...");
         //Insert the custom action to launch the application when finished
        sql = "INSERT INTO `CustomAction` (`Action`, `Type`, `Source`, `Target`) VALUES ('VSDCA_Launch1', '210', '" + fileId + "', '')";
        view = database.OpenView(sql);
        view.Execute();
        view.Close();

        if (checkboxChecked)
        {
               WScript.Echo("Updating the Property table...");
              // Set the default value of the CheckBox
             sql = "INSERT INTO `Property` (`Property`, `Value`) VALUES ('LAUNCHAPP2', '1')";
            view = database.OpenView(sql);
           view.Execute();
          view.Close();
        }

        database.Commit();
        WScript.Echo("Done...");
```

Comment: currently it creates one checkbox which launches both apps and I need two that launches each one based on checked.

Comment: The current issue is that one check box doesn't appear until I move the mouse(probably causing a redraw?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A checkbox control has multiple attributes unique to it, but you are mostly interested in the property name, property value and text. The checkbox property value is used to determine if the custom action which launches your file is executed or not.

If you are encountering problems, you should offer more details about what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: I am only getting one checkbox and both exes are launching when it is checked. I can provide the .js I am using

Comment: After further review of my code I noticed I was drawing the checkboxes on top of each other by mistake. >_<