# How to run an application as soon as installation is completed?

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer

I am writing an installer for a c# application using visual studio 2008.There i have created a setup project and created the .msi file also.it is working properly.Now I need to run my application at the end of the installation.Is there any way to override the installer class to do that?
need a help

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Orca from microsoft which lets you read and edit msi files.  That helped me puzzle out a different problem with installs.

And check this out [Run exe after msi installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668274/run-exe-after-msi-installation)

Comment: you could use WIX to build your MSI as part of your solution build, but not sure it allows you to run arbitrary executable after install

Answer (score 0):

does it have to be in MSI ? why not have a batch file (run.bat) and run your msi first followed by your app

Comment: Are you completely sure that the batch file would wait the msi execution to complete and terminate before trying to run the next command?

Comment: yes, i would have though so, otherwise some of our batch files would be in big trouble :)