# Launch Application after Installation is complete

Tags: c#, windows-installer, setup-deployment

I have an application in c#.net and I have added setup and deployment project in it.
here everything is working fine but now I want the application to get launched after I finish with my installation.

It should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: which VS version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the most rated answer for your question here:

[Run exe after msi installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668274/run-exe-after-msi-installation)

Comment: I'm getting an Error: 'PostBuildEvent' failed with error code '1' 'Unspecified error'

Comment: check this to solve that error: http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/230/1/Error-There-is-no-script-engine-for-file-extension-when-running-js-files.html