# VB.NET 2005 launch application after install

Tags: vb.net, installation

I'm using the built in setup project. I've tried the commit event on the installer but that is fired before the installer quits, not after. Also I've tried this guy's code:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/08/12/696833.aspx

His goal is the same as mine but when I try to get his code to run on the post build event, it errors out with "unspecified error"...

How do I get the installer to run my app after it installs? You know, with the checkbox thing "Launch after finish."???

This should be soooo simple.........

*Frustrated*

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668274/run-exe-after-msi-installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, they guy's blog is right. I got it to work and it's exactly what I was looking for. To figure out what went wrong, I showed the output window (CTRL+ALT+O) and it showed the CScript output for the post build event when his script was being called. It turns out that .js files on my system were being handled by Notepad++ and I needed to change the association to CScript for his script to work (CScript won't work with .vbs or .js files if it isn't the default application for the file... so stupid). I also had to unassociate Notepad++ with .js files in Notepad++'s settings because it would recapture the file association when I restarted Notepad++.