# msi installer postbuildevent cscript "$(ProjectDir)EnableLaunchApplication.js" "$(BuiltOuputPath)"

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I have MSI installer project where 
postbuildevent == cscript "$(ProjectDir)EnableLaunchApplication.js" "$(BuiltOuputPath)"

1 Question that I've been struggling for hours - how do I prevent running this script on uninstall - i.e. run it ONLY on install?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668274/run-exe-after-msi-installation  - this is what i am using now. But I see "Run application" checkbox on uninstall too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this thread](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/08/12/696833.aspx?PageIndex=2), I modified/added these lines:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `ControlEvent` (`Dialog_`, `Control_`, `Event`, `Argument`, `Condition`, `Ordering`) VALUES ('FinishedForm', 'CloseButton', 'DoAction', 'VSDCA_Launch', 'LAUNCHAPP=1 AND NOT REMOVE', '0')";

sql = "INSERT INTO `ControlCondition` (`Dialog_`, `Control_`, `Action`, `Condition`) VALUES ('FinishedForm', 'CheckboxLaunch', 'Hide', 'Installed')";
view = database.OpenView(sql);
view.Execute();
view.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

post build events don't run on install nor on uninstall. they run post build