# Run exe after msi installation - App doesn`t run?

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I read this thread
[Run exe after msi installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668274/run-exe-after-msi-installation)

I followed the instructions and I have weird problem.
When I install the MSI from VS (right-click on installer project and select install), the script works perfectly but when I run the installation from the MSI file
I see the checkbox but it does nothing – the application doesn't run.

Anyone know what can be the cause for this?

Comment: Did you look through the msi logs? Does the app run when you run installation from VS?

Comment: Yes application run when I installing directly from VS. Where can I see MSI logs?

Comment: Run you package as follows: `msiexec /i product.msi /lvx* installation.log`. Replace `product.msi` with the name of your MSI file. The log will be written to `installation.log` file. Look around the end of the log where you're trying to start your application: search for property name associated with your checkbox control and check whether Custom Action to start is run or not.

Comment: Did you condition this to run on first install, and then overlook to uninstall before trying to install from the MSI? Some of the examples require the full UI and a first install only e.g.  Using a [Custom Action to Launch an Installed File at the End of the Installation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/6b082559-bcfa-4098-b072-27ee78092833)

Comment: Eventually I created console application that run install and after it run my application. I succseeded in runing app after install but it runs under system user and it`s not good for me. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I created console application that run install and after it run my application. 
I succseeded in runing app after install but it runs under system user and it`s not good for me

Comment: What is the EXE file that should run after the install doing? Could its task be performed by the main EXE itself based on a flag in the registry saying a fresh install has been performed?