# Run exe after msi installation as administrator

Tags: windows-installer, custom-action

I'm trying to create installation that would run .exe file as administrator at the end.
I found this post [Run exe after msi installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668274/run-exe-after-msi-installation) that explains how to run .exe after installation but if I change app.manifest in my source to have `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` this solution will not work.
Is there any workaround for this?

Thank you

Comment: Why does the EXE need to run as admin?  What does it do?

Comment: Not sure what "will not work" means exactly, but I suspect you will not see an elevation dialog because those type 18 custom actions are run via a CreateProcess type of initiation which does not use a manifest. So you'll see it running as the installing user and not elevated. Your checkbox custom action needs to be code that starts a shell execute run of that program, the difference between wscript.run and wscript.exec, or the use of C# Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute as examples of the difference.

Comment: Is the MSI installation running elevated?  It doesn't really make sense for the user to discover that they need admin rights only after the installation is almost finished.