# What is the privilege level for post install run of msi using the EnableLaunchApplication.js script in Visual Studio?

Tags: installation, setup-deployment, visual-studio-setup-proje, vsinstaller

Using Visual Studio Installer Project I can launch a post install option using the script given here: 
[Run exe after msi installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668274/run-exe-after-msi-installation/2998791#2998791)

The question is does the launched program run in elevated privileged mode or revert to the unprivileged user mode?

I have successfully used the script and the program launches fine but I am unsure if it is running as a normal user.

To add the script I add this under Deployment Project Properties

PostBuildEvent: cscript.exe "$(ProjectDir)EnableLaunchApplication.js" "$(BuiltOuputPath)"

It launches fine. I just don't know how to tell what user is running it (admin or standard)

Comment: Check in `Task Manager`, `Details view`, `"User Name" column`. What does it say?